# NFS Mounting from apache2 php worked as expected under Ubuntu 16 but not Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, apache2, php, nfs

I have php code for apache2 that is supposed to mount NFS filesystems on the server. They have the form of exec("some scripts that do the mount that has the correct sudo permissions");

This worked fine and as expected on ubuntu 16. After mounting I could do a 'df' and the mounted volume would appear and I could access it as expected.

Under ubuntu 18, the behavior is different and I don't understand it. It seems to do a virtual or temporary mount but nobody but www-data user can access it. In other words, I do php

exec("mount script");
exec("df > some_log_file");

and some_log_file will show the mount. But if at the same time I log into the server, either directly on the display or via ssh, and I type 'df' it does NOT appear (nor is it accessible in any other way even as root).

I'm guessing this might have something to do with systemd since it's sort of like the PrivateTmp thing, but I can't even figure out what string to type into google to figure out what's going on.

Note: this is an apache server that is on an isolated LAN NOT connected to the Internet so there is no security risk so you needn't point the riskiness out.

Comment: How about; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace

Comment: Hello, as workaround, if the mountpoint is inside `/tmp`, try with different mountpoint outside.. I think your assumption *this might have something to do with systemd since it's sort of like the PrivateTmp thing* is right.

Comment: The mount point wasn't in /tmp but I'll try mounting other places.